# Selenium doesn't open (complex) url

Tags: python, selenium, htmlunit

I'm using Selenium in Python with remote and HTMLUNIT. When doing a driver.get(url), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'ReferenceError: "AsyncHttpObject" is not defined.
```

My url is of the following format:

http://www.test.com?date1=01-Mar-2013%2010:00:01&date2=07-Mar-2013%2010:00:01&xx=yy&etc=etc

If I exclude the date1 and date2 fields, it works. If I include any of the fields, it doesn't work.
I tried formatting them in multiple encodings:

- date1=01-Mar-2013%2010:00:01
- date1=01-Mar-2013 2010:00:01
- date1=01-Mar-2013%2010%3A00%3A01
- date1=01-Mar-2013+2010%3A00%3A01

Weird thing is that if I use Firefox instead of remote (HTMLUNIT), it works.

I tried searching what is AsyncHttpObject, but to no success.

Answer (score 2):

The URL cannot contain any character. That is why you need to "encode" the url before using it in any query.

Visit [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for all encoded characters. Notice that ":" would be "%3A" in a encoded URL.

So "test.com?date=10:10:10" should be "test.com?date=10%3A10%3A10".

There are tools in python like urlencode() from urllib module that can help you do it better. For those, check urllib.urlencode documentation.